# Anime set in modern Tokyo where players are given matches on their phones and have to fight to the death

Tags: story-identification, anime

It's a battle royal type anime set in modern Tokyo, where the players are given matches on their phones.

As players, they are given a gift that will allow them to do something awesome. The players have to fight to the death and the loser will be digitized out leaving little blocks missing in the ground around them.

The main character's special ability turns out to be creation, so he creates guns to fight with. He also befriends a girl that uses a whip sword to fight with. That's all I can remember.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this might be *[Darwin's Game](https://myanimelist.net/anime/38656/Darwins_Game)*.

> High school student Kaname Sudou receives an invitation from a classmate to play Darwin's Game, a mobile game he has never heard of. However, as soon as he opens the application, a green snake suddenly pops out from his phone screen and bites his neck, leaving him unconscious. Waking up in the infirmary without any signs of a snake bite, he is told by the school to take the rest of the day off. Although he is puzzled by what has happened, he dismisses the surreal experience as a hallucination and boards the train home.
>
> Unfortunately, his curiosity gets the better of him and he uses the application once again. As the application appears to be just like any other battle game, Kaname breathes out a sigh of relief and decides to start his first match. However, the pleasant surprise is short-lived, as his in-game opponent unexpectedly appears right in front of him and attempts to hunt him down with a knife.
>
> As he desperately runs for his life, Kaname puts two and two together and realizes that Darwin's Game is not an ordinary game, but rather, it's a brutal fight for survival.

[The Wikipedia page for the manga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin%27s_Game) says the following about the male lead, Kaname Sudō:

> His Sigil "The Fire God's Hammer", allows him to recreate weapons and other simple objects he has touched before, in addition to modifying them to his will, although this exhausts him easily and the objects created will disappear should he lose consciousness.

The same page says the following about the female lead, Shuka Karino:

> She later becomes Kaname's main romantic interest. Her Sigil "Princess of Thorn" allows her to control wire-like objects, which she utilises to wield spiked chains.

At [1:10](https://youtu.be/_cLxzQoNVpo?t=75) in the trailer, there's a still image of the male lead holding a handgun and the female lead holding a chain with a spike on the end of it.

Comment: Ooh yes..you see the whip sword and manifesting guns in the trailer.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [*Deadman Wonderland*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadman_Wonderland)?

Boy fights death matches with others in post-apocalyptic Tokyo

**Warning:NSFW (Gory)**.